Why does my Mirabelle de Nancy produce abundant foliage but no blossom?
Mirabelle de Nancy plum tree about 3 years old produces no blossom but dense foliage.
The tree being trained as a double stemmed fan. This shape to comply with the form of the tree as I received it .It had been damaged at an early stage in life. My method of training is to bend horizontally each suitable lateral up and over the preceding one giving a layered/step ladder effect. In fact the tree has never actually been pruned- the shape being derived from bending young laterals into a series of horizontal steps.
I have several other fruit trees between 6 and 1 year old trained as espalier or fan all thriving and all, even the most recently planted  have flowered this season apart from the Mirabelle which has never flowered but produces abundant foliage. All earlier planted trees have yielded some fruit.
Location is Aberdeenshire. Garden is a portion of a previous walled-garden. Walls face due south and due west with good fertility.
I suspect the unconventional 'pruning' method may be the cause of the unexpected behaviour.
Any observations, advice would be very welcome. The plant is not too old to be rectified.
G T S
.

Pictures please!
